# malloc and scope

Tags: c, malloc, scope

I am struggling to wrap my head around malloc in c - specifically when it needs to be free()'d.  I am getting weird errors in gcc such as:

`... free(): invalid next size (fast): ...`

when I try to free a char pointer.  For example, when reading from an input file, it will crash on certain lines when doing the following:

```
FILE *f = fopen(file,"r");
char x[256];
while(1) {
    if(fgets(x,sizeof x,f)==NULL) break;
    char *tmp = some_function_return_char_pointer(x); //OR malloc(nbytes);
    // do some stuff
    free(tmp); // this is where I get the error, but only sometimes
}
```

I checked for obvious things, such as x being NULL, but it's not; it just crashes on random lines.

But my REAL question is - **when do I need to use free()**?  Or, probably more correctly, when should I NOT use free? What if malloc is in a function, and I return the var that used malloc()? What about in a for or while loop?  Does malloc-ing for an array of struct have the same rules as for a string/char pointer?

I gather from the errors I'm getting in gcc on program crash that I'm just not understanding malloc and free.  I've spent my quality time with Google and I'm still hitting brick walls.  Are there any good resources you've found?  Everything I see says that whenever I use malloc I need to use free.  But then I try that and my program crashes.  So maybe it's different based on a variable's scope?  Does C free the memory at the end of a loop when a variable is declared inside of it? At the end of a function?

So:

```
for(i=0;i<100;i++) char *x=malloc(n); // no need to use free(x)?
```

but:

```
char *x;
for(i=0;i<100;i++) {
    x=malloc(n);
    free(x); //must do this, since scope of x greater than loop?
}
```

Is that right?

Hopefully I'm making sense...

Comment: anything you malloc(), you free (once) when you no longer need to use it.

Comment: are you malloc'ing zero bytes...? http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/578467-what-malloc-0-should-returns ***EDIT:*** Just realized this wont matter, as you can still `free(...)` the pointer, regardless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`malloc()` is C's *dynamic allocator*. You have to understand the difference between automatic (scoped) and dynamic (manual) variables.

Automatic variables live for the duration of their scope. They're the ones you declare without any decoration: `int x;`

*Most* variables in a C program should be automatic, since they are local to some piece of code (e.g. a function, or a loop), and they communicate via function calls and return values.

The *only* time you need dynamic allocation is when you have some data that needs to outlive any given scope. Such data must be allocated dynamically, and eventually freed when it is no longer necessary.

The prime usage example for this is your typical *linked list*. The list nodes cannot possibly be local to any scope if you are going to have generic "insert/erase/find" list manipulation functions. Thus, each node must be allocated dynamically, and the list manipulation functions must ensure that they free those nodes that are no longer part of the list.

In summary, variable allocation is fundamentally and primarily a question of *scope*. If possible keep everything automatic and you don't have to do anything. If necessary, use dynamic allocation and take care to deallocate manually whenever appropriate.

(*Edit:* As @Oli says, you may also want to use dynamic allocation in a strictly local context at times, because most platforms limit the size of automatic variables to a much smaller limit than the size of dynamic memory. Think "huge array". Exceeding the available space for automatic variables usually has a colourful name such as "pile overrun" or something similar.)

Comment: +1 for the advice to avoid dynamic allocation whenever possible.

Comment: An instance of dynamic allocation that isn't down to outliving scope is when you need a massive array (e.g. a million elements) that would smash the stack.

Comment: The way you explained it definitely helped.  Coming from PHP where `$x = "some string";`, I was trying to use `malloc` has the replacement for assignment; it makes much more sense to describe it as dynamic, and not automatic, allocation

Comment: Awesome explanation of when it's (not) appropriate to `malloc`ate

Answer (score 3):

In general, every call to `malloc` must have **one** corresponding call to `free`.<sup>*</sup>  This has nothing to do with scope (i.e. nothing to do with functions or loops).

---

<sub>* Exceptions to this rule include using functions like `strdup`, but the principle is the same.</sub>

Comment: It's important to note here, that calling `free(...)` twice could lead to a crash.

Comment: @xixonia: A crash is the best-case scenario and not what you should expect. The worst-case is giving an attacker root.

Comment: @R.., this all just make me want to get back in to C :)

Answer (score 2):

Broadly speaking, every pointer that is ever returned by `malloc()` must eventually be passed to `free()`. The scope of the variable that you store the pointer *in* does not affect this, because even after the variable is no longer in scope, the memory that the pointer points to will still be allocated until you call `free()` on it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the scope of the malloc'd memory lays between calls to `malloc` and `free` or otherwise until process is stopped (that is when OS cleans up for the process). If you never call `free` you get a memory leak. That could happen when address that you can pass to `free` goes out of scope before you actually used it - that is like loosing your keys for the car, car is still there but you can't really drive it. The error you are getting is most likely either because function returns a pointer to some memory that was not allocated using `malloc` or it returns a null pointer which you pass to `free`, which you cannot do.

Comment: You mean "lifetime", not "scope".  Scope applies to identifiers, not objects.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the word in C is "storage duration", not "lifetime". :-)

Comment: @R..: No, I really do mean "lifetime"; see 6.2.4 clause 2.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, oh snap fighting words   ::pops popcorn::

Answer (score 0):

You should free memory when you will no longer be accessing it. You should not free memory if you will be accessing it. This will give you a lot of pain.

Answer (score 0):

malloc(n) allocates n bytes of memory from a memory location named heap and then returns a void* type of pointer to it. The memory is allocated at runtime. Once you have allocated a memory dynamically, scope does not matter as long as you keep a pointer to it with you(or the address of it specifically). For example:

```
int* allocate_an_integer_array(int n)
{
    int* p = (int*) (malloc(sizeof(int)*n));
    return p;
}
```

This functions simply allocates memory from heap equal to n integers and returns a pointer to the first location. The pointer can be used in the calling function as you want to. The SCOPE does not matter as long as the pointer is with you..

free(p) returns the memory to heap.

The only thing you need to remember is to free it as if you don't free it and lose the value of its address, there will bw a memory leak. It is so because according to OS, you are still using the memory as you have not freed it and a memory leak will happen..

Also after freeing just set the value of the pointer to null so that u don't use it again as the same memory may be allocated again at any other time for a different purpose....

So, all you need to do is to be careful...

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want [memory leak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak), you have to free the memory from malloc.

It can be very tricky. For example, if the `// do some stuff` has a `continue`, the free will be skipped and lead to memory leak. It is tricky, so we have shared_ptr in C++; and rumor has it salary of C programmer is higher than C++ programmer.

Sometimes we don't care memory leak. If the memory holds something that is needed during the whole lifetime of execution, you can choose not to free it. Example: a string for environment variable.

PS: [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) is a tool to help detect memory bugs. Especially useful for memory leak.

Comment: Neglecting to free something just because it's lifetime is the whole of execution is very poor practice.  For a start, it swamps your Valgrind output with errors.

Comment: I agree. But we have to live with that.

Comment: You don't only if you are the only one to write codes, and don't use any library. Reality is your colleagues code like this; and the libraries you relies on may not free the memory.

Comment: If my colleagues leave a memory leak in library code, I raise a ticket and get them to fix it...

Comment: Alright, you have a point. I am going to convince my colleagues to free the memory for putenv(strdup(...)). I will try to get them work. Thank you.